# Google Apps Script: People API gets few contacts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-people-api

Since from April the Contacts API will be deprecated I'm making the switch to the People API.

I'm using the code suggested by Google to find a contact starting from email. This is the function:

```
function getContactByEmail(email) {
   var email = "anExistingMailInMyContacts@gmail.com";

   try {
     // Gets the person with that email address by iterating over all contacts.
     const people = People.People.Connections.list('people/me', {
       personFields: 'names,emailAddresses'
     });
     const contact = people['connections'].find((connection) => {
       const emailAddresses = connection['emailAddresses'];
       return emailAddresses && emailAddresses.length > 0 && emailAddresses.some((emailAddress) => emailAddress['value'] === email);
     });
     // Prints the contact.
     console.log('People: %s', JSON.stringify(people, null, 2));
     console.log('Contact: %s', JSON.stringify(contact, null, 2));
   } catch (err) {
     // TODO (developers) - Handle exception
     console.log('Failed to get the connection with an error %s', err.message);
   }
}
```

The problem is that the People API only fetch a very small subset of my contacts.
Thanks to the line console.log('People: %s', JSON.stringify(people, null, 2)); I discovered that there are only very few contacts extracted. And they are always the same.

Ho can I fetch all my contacts?

Comment: Perhaps you need to utilize the nextPageToken and perform paging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Cooper says is true. It is possible that your response is not complete because you are just counting on the result from the first page.

> Perhaps you need to utilize the nextPageToken and perform paging.

You can obtain all pages of the response by using this code as sample:

```
function myFunction() {
  console.log("Printing contacts: ")
  let allConnections = listAllContacts();

  allConnections.forEach(function(connection) { console.log(connection.names[0].displayName) })
}

function listAllContacts(){
  let allContacts = []
  var nextPageToken;
  let pageNumber = 0

  do {
    console.log("Getting page " + ++pageNumber + " with nextPageToken: " + nextPageToken)
    var response = getContacts(nextPageToken);
    allContacts = allContacts.concat(response.connections)
  } while (nextPageToken = response.nextPageToken)

  return allContacts;
}

function getContacts(nextPageToken = null) {
  return PeopleAPI.People.Connections.list("people/me", {
    personFields: "names",
    pageToken: nextPageToken,
    pageSize: 5
  });
}
```

This is the result of the console:

[image: Image showing the output to console from a code adding all contacts from an API response with the people.connections.list method]

The [***people.connections.list***](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list) **method** will only return the contacts under your https://contacts.google.com/ contacts page. To get the contacts under *Other contacts* use the [***otherContacts.list***](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/otherContacts/list) **method** instead.

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly. I had to insert an "if" statement for the first console.log:
if (connection.emailAddresses && connection.emailAddresses.length > 0 && connection.emailAddresses[0].value) {
    console.log(connection.emailAddresses[0].value);
  } else {
    console.log("No name found for contact");
  }
This is because the some contacts didn't have a name.

Answer (score 0):

You can add pageSize
// Gets the person with that email address by iterating over all contacts.
const people = People.People.Connections.list('people/me', {
personFields: 'names,emailAddresses',
pageSize: 500
});